# How is classification mathematically done in SVM if target is labeled as 0 and 1?

Tags: python, classification, svm

My dataset has feature columns and a target label of 0 and 1.

When I use SVM classifier for binary classification it predicts well.

But my question is how is it mathematically predicted.?

The marginal hyperplanes H1 and H2 have the equations:
W^T X +b >= 1

meaning if greater than +1 it falls in one class.  And if less than -1, it falls in another class.

But we have given the target label 0 and 1.

How actually is it done mathematically?

Anyone expert please.....

Answer (score 1):

Basically, SVM wants to find the optimal hyperplane that splits the datapoints in such way that the margin between the closest datapoints of each class (the so-called support vectors) is maximized. This all breaks down to the following Lagrangian optimization problem:
[image]

- **w**:vector that determines the optimum hyperplane ( for intuition, make yourself familiar with the geometrical meaning of a dot product)
- **(w^T∙x_i+b)** is a  scalar and displays the geometrical distance
  between single datapoint x_i and the maximum margin hyperplane
- **b** is a bias vector ( I think it comes from indetermined integral in
  derivation of SVM) more on that you can find here: [University Stanford -Computer Science Lecture 3-SVM](http://cs229.stanford.edu/summer2019/cs229-notes1.pdf)
- **λ_i** the Lagrangian multiplier
- **y_i** the normalized classification boundary

Solving the optimization problem leads to all necessary parameters of w, b, and lambda.

To answer you quesiton in one sentence: The class boundaries [-1,1] are set arbitrarily. It is really just definition.
[image]

The labels of your binary data [0;1] (so-called dummy varaibles) have nothing to with the boundaries. It is just a convenient way to label binary data. The labels are only needed to link the features to its corresponding class or category.

The only non paramter in Formula (8) is x_i , your datapoint in feature space.

At least thats how I understand SVM. **Feel free to correct me if I am wrong or unprecise.**

Comment: Dear  @Epimetheus , thank you for your justification. If I label my Target as (0 and 1), is it okay ? Or Do I have to label it as (-1 and  +1) .

Comment: No, you dont need to update your labels :)

Comment: "The class boundaries [-1,1] are set arbitrarily. " what does it mean? Actually in my dataset, Clickbaits are labelled 0 and Non-clickbaits are labelled as 1. But how datapoints with label 0 are classified to either one of the class? A bit unclear.

Comment: @ShivaRD the boundaries are just defined mathematically this way. see above. There is no need for an already labeled datapoint to be classified. A new datapoint is classified as either Clickbait or no Clickbait depending on the datapoints features. What kind of features do you use?

Comment: The featured dataset uses TFIDF and cosine similarity  with Target (0 and 1). But while training the SVM model, the datapoints need  to be classified as 0 or 1, is not it?

Comment: The labels are only of importance when elicting the features (tfidf, cosine) not for the training process.

Comment: @ShivaRD , if you accept the answer (check mark) you can help that others are able to  find that solution in the future.